# Update twitter status without prompting user using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, twitter

I have web application where people can login from twitter and based on their preference and DOM events I need update their status on twitter. I have a good idea how to do this on server side, but for this project I am not using any server side code, So how can I do this by just javascript, @anywhere twitter api and twitter intents are taking me to no where because they prompt user for submitting the tweet which I dont want.

Comment: Sounds like abuse waiting to happen. I agree with Twitter.

Answer (score 3):

A pure Javascript solution to consume twitter API is not possible without compromising your consumer secret key. Twitter API authenticates every request using a HMAC-SHA1 token, the SHA1  token is generated using the public/private key assigned by twitter to your api account. If you plan to generate this token using a pure javascript SHA1 implementation then it means you will be exposing your private key in the javascript code which anyone can look at.

Even though technically its possible (provided you can find a javascript library which implements SHA1), its not advisable.

FYI, jQuery.Ajax method does let you modify the headers of the ajax request by tapping in to the beforeSend(jqXHR, settings) method.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with an AJAX POST request to the REST API.  Documentation: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update

You target the URL `http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.format`, where `format` can be either `xml` or `json`, and reflects the format of the response.  Required data is the status text, and there are several optional parameters which I won't list here.  This only works for the currently authenticated user.

An (untested) example using jQuery:

```
var message = "This is a tweet, there are many like it but this one is mine";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json",
    data: "status="+message,
    datatype: "json"
});
```

Comment: no, it is not working, i believe authentication tokens has to be sent as HTTP request headers. Which are not sent in $.ajax() method.

Comment: It seemed a bit too simple. The oAuth tokens don't _have_ to be sent using headers though.  Assuming that you authorised the user and have all the required information, you can construct an access token using the steps described here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth#auth-request (I never said it would be easy!)

Comment: @ShivDeepak: Im pretty sure you can custumize headers when doing Ajax.

Comment: jQuery.Ajax method does let you modify the headers of the ajax request by tapping in to the beforeSend(jqXHR, settings) method. However its not advisable to consume twitter's API via javascript, see my answer.